# Build Dropbear dbclient binary for Android

Tags: android, c, ssh, linker, arm

I'd like to use an ssh client in the Android terminal emulator, to connect to remote systems, when I have to.

There are a couple other ways to do this -- using separate Java apps, *purchasing* separate Java-based apps, etc.

Really, I just want to build and deploy a statically-linked dbclient binary that can do libnss hostname lookups. ("Woo! Tall order.")

There are a number of bits of documentation on howto build Dropbear for Android. Many focus on the non-client bins, but not all:

- [Running dropbear on Android...](http://cri.ch/sven/doku.php/blog/running-dropbear-on-android)
- [Howto cross-compile dropbear...](http://roycormier.net/2010/11/02/cross-compiling-dropbear-sshd-for-android/)
- [Howto build/compile dropbearmulti](http://code.google.com/p/droidsshd/wiki/BuildingDropbear)

The dynamic linked build doesn't exec on my target, and I don't have strace or ldd to help troubleshoot.

The static linked build runs, but can't get hostnames because of missing runtime support. Fine, so patch that out -- still doesn't work. It just hangs. Again, I don't know why.

The busybox-style dropbearmulti exhibits the same behavior.

So, million dollar question: has anyone actually gotten this to work? Do you have documentation of your experience?

I'm targeting a rooted 2.3.7 Gingerbread build on a Samsung Infuse 4G (generic armeabi).

Answer (score 5):

I make Android-NDK dynamic ssh-dropbear-ssh-client only. See 
ftp://ftp.simtreas.ru/pub/my/dropbear/dropbear-ssh-only.tgz
sourse and ftp://ftp.simtreas.ru/pub/my/dropbear/ssh binary